# CompiledFunction fails for Variance with a rank 3 input

Tags: probability-or-statistics, compile

Why does compiling `Variance` for a rank 3 input fail but `Mean` works?

```
meanC =
 Compile[
  {{mat, _Real, 3}},
  Mean[mat],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ];

varianceC =
 Compile[
  {{mat, _Real, 3}},
  Variance[mat],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ];
```

Test on data

```
SeedRandom[1];
r = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 3, 4}];

meanC[r] == Mean[r];
```

> True

But

```
varianceC[r] == Variance[r]
```

> [image]

[image]

> True

Comment: I'm wondering, `Mean`and `Variance`both aren't compilerfunctions: "Compile
`CompilerFunctions[] // Sort"

Comment: I see that they are in the "second list" here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions

Comment: Variance takes vectors or matrices as input not. Change your definitions accordingly.

Comment: @DanielHuber I would've have expected it to behave the same way as `Mean`